# How do I correct my refrigerator water dispenser angle on a new fridge?

Tags: refrigerator

I recently got a Samsung side by side refrigerator. Everything is working great except for the water dispenser. The water comes out at an angle and misses the cup when dispensing water. In order to avoid a spill, I have to push the button with my hand and then position the cup just right with my other hand. Is there a way to make an adjustment to the nozzle so the water dispenses straight down?

Comment: Call the manufacture with the issue. They may have a quick solution, or order you a new refrigerator.

Answer (score 2):

> ...recently got...

Usually implies that the product is still under warranty. Call the manufacturer with a warranty claim and have them either walk you through an approved, DIY fix, or ask them to send a factory certified tech to do the repair.

Anything you DIY right now will likely be an excuse for them to void your warranty, causing you to have to pay for any further repairs.

I applaud your DIY spirit, and, 10 years from now when it's out of warranty, sure, tear into it and fix it yourself. But if it's brand new...

Comment: Note "got" doesn't necessarily mean it was brand new!

Comment: True, however, "usually implies" isn't a statement of fact in all cases. It's the basis of assumption for my answer, and until the OP states otherwise, I'm sticking with it.